# Why this error ? "The type or namespace name 'c' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Tags: c#, asp.net

The type or namespace name 'c' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I do have this namespace added "using System.Web.UI.WebControls;" why this error ??

```
 protected void DoSomething(Control control)(
    {

        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        { 
            if(typeof(c).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))
            {
               Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor rad = c as Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor;
               rad.CssClass = "MyStyle";
                  label1.Visible = true; label1.Text = "dhchk";
               // control.CssFiles.Add("~/styles/myStyle.css"); 
            }
            else
            {
                  DoSomething(c);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `c` is if it was a type, not a varaible.

Change this:

```
if (typeof(c).Equals(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))
```

into:

```
if (c.GetType().Equals(typeof(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)))
```

or simply:

```
if (c is Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)
```

Comment: thnx the last one worked..now there's another error when I try adding CSS classes to RadEditor this way " rad.CssClasses.Add("../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css");" ..The Error is "The best overloaded method match for 'Telerik.Web.StronglyTypedStateManagedCollection<Telerik.Web.UI.EditorCssClass>.Add(Telerik.Web.UI.EditorCssClass)' has some invalid arguments" i need to add like 4 CSS classes to every radEditor control ...Isnt that the correct way ?what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: @Serenity: The `CssClasses.Add` method is for adding a single class name to the CSS class dropdown. You want to use the `CssFiles.Add` method instead.

Answer (score 3):

typeof(x) expects x to be a Type, not an Object.

Use this instead

```
if(c is Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)
```

A correct use of typeof is

```
if (c.GetType().Equals(typeof(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `typeof(...)` operator needs to be given a type name, known at compile time. I think you *actually* meant:

```
if (c.GetType().Equals(typeof(Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)))
```

However, it would be better to write:

```
RadEditor editor = c as Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor;
if (editor != null)
{
    rad.CssClass = "MyStyle";
    label1.Visible = true;
    label1.Text = "dhchk";
}
```

This would then *also* cope with the situation where `c` is an instance of a subclass of `RadEditor`, which I assume should go down the same path.

By using `as` once instead of `is` then `as` or a cast, you only have to do the dynamic type checking once - it's generally neater.

Comment: how do I add more than one css class to the RadEditor controls..I need to add 4

Comment: tried this but its not working.. "rad.CssClasses.Add("../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css");rad.CssClasses.Add("../Skins/CustomSkin/ToolBar.CustomSkin.css"); "

Comment: um do I need to ask this in a separate ques? that type error got resolved..stuck with this one now

Comment: @Serenity: I would ask that as a separate question, yes - it doesn't sound related, and is actually more to do with the Telerik control than C# itself.

Comment: +1 for using `as` instead of doing multiple runtime type queries. Using `is` and *then* `as` never makes sense, though—if you’ve already verified the type or *require* something to be a particular type, just use a cast.